# Should I separate Web app from Web Server for multi platform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, multiplatform

My question is whether I should have a single server serving HTML and JSON or separate those two.

To be more specific these are the pieces of my two options:

1)

- API server running Python in Google App Engine
- Web app running Rails in Heroku
- iOS app
- Android app

The Web, iOS and Android apps would query the API server to retrieve information like list of entities to display in the app.

2)

- Server running Rails in Heroku
- iOS app
- Android app

The Rails server would be a regular Rails app and would have API URLs to serve the iOS and Android when the necessary JSON with the list of entities.

Which approach should I take and why?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest separate servers for them. If one server crashes or has other issues then only one of your platforms will have an issue. Also, a server has a capacity before it "freaks out" if your server can only handle 1,000 people on it and each of your platforms have 500 people on it then your server is over capacity with only 500 people on 1 of the platforms.

You could keep it on one server especially if you don't have a lot of traffic. In my experience, I had a website turned into an app with one server. Not too many people were on the website but the app did which caused the website to also crash once the server hit capacity.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If the Python server crashes, all platforms will have the issue.

Comment: I don't get your comment about the traffic, if I have 500 people on each platform, the Python server will still be subjected to 1500 people.